# How to develop separate visual identities for different educational programs on the same website

Tags: website-design, design-principles, branding, user-experience, identity

I have been asked to work on a visual identity project.
The company is an academy (parent company)  which has a single website.
However, the academy separates its programs into 4 fields of music education, which are all hosted on the same website under different webpages, for example:

[www.parentcompany.com/Field_1](http://www.parentcompany.com/Field_1)

[www.parentcompany.com/Field_2](http://www.parentcompany.com/Field_2)

[www.parentcompany.com/Field_3](http://www.parentcompany.com/Field_3)

[www.parentcompany.com/Field_4](http://www.parentcompany.com/Field_4)

All the pages feature a large logo of the parent company in a navigation bar fixed to the top of the screen/page (always visible when scrolling), and all use the same colour scheme.
Though beneath the navigation bar (containing the parent company logo) there is a large page header containing a separate logo for each field of education (not visible when you scroll down). Each logo is quite different, but without colour / all black and white at the moment. I have attached an example screenshot of the page structures:

[image]

Whilst they teach 4 fields of music, they only want to focus on and promote one of these for the meantime (and near future). With the idea that eventually each program would be recognised and promoted as separate entities with their own distinct visual identities, rather than promoting the academy as a whole.

I have been asked to develop the branding for the one field they are focusing on at the moment. However, they are not currently interested in developing the identity of the academy as a whole.

Initially I was thinking it may be best to tie the visual identity of each program into the academy identity, and suggest working on both the academy and program identities. However, other than the fact that the company is not interested in developing the visual design of the academy at the moment, it also seems aiming to tie all the programs and parent company together in some way could be quite tricky and restricting.

**Questions:**

**I am uncertain what may be the best way, or recommended practices, to approach this?** i.e. If the visual identity of just one program is quite distinct, how to approach this if all the programs are hosted on the same parent company website, which also has its own separate logo and visual identity (though which is quite neutral/basic)?

**What consideration could be taken into account to prevent the visual design of just one program from fragmenting the visual design of the website in a way that could become confusing?**

Thanks for any information.

Comment: Welcome! Are you building a brand or a web site? Or both? If it's just the brand, then none of the web site integration is your problem, focus on the brand you're being paid to develop. If it's a website or both, I don't see how you can merely "ignore" the parent company branding since it's integral to the website itself.

Comment: Hi, cheers for the reply. They currently already have a website, although an agency is developing a new version, however it seems like the structure of having all the separate programs on the academy website will be the same. Wondering if it’s worth accounting for anything in particular when developing a visual identity for the separate programs. In order to create the effective system? Rather than treating each program as a completely separate project.